# Compilation error while trying to use "current" macros

Tags: linux, kernel, task

```
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct task_struct *task;
    task = current;
    printf("Proc PID is %ld\n",(long)task->pid);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I get the following error when I try to compile:

```
*current.c: In function ‘main’:
current.c:9:9: error: ‘current’ undeclared (first use in this function)
current.c:9:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
current.c:10:40: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type*
```

I'm using Linux Kernel 3.2.0.4-amd64.
Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you try to use the data structures, variables of Linux Kernel in user space programming? If so, you make mistake. The task_struct is internal data structure of the Linux Kernel. And current is also internal Linux Kernel register variable. User space program can not use them.

Comment: Thx. So what's the correct way to experiment with kernel's API and build a sample code which works?

Comment: I think you can create one kernel module to experiment with kernel's API.

Comment: This quick manual will answer to your question http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/